# Stop Azure EventBus Receiver from inside onEvent

Tags: python, azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub

I am using the Python Azure Event Hub package, and have the following code:

```
    def on_event(partition_context, event):
        print("Received event from partition: {}.".format(partition_context.partition_id))
        event_json = json.loads(str(event))
        if event_json["command_status"]=="successull":
           # STOP RECEIVER HERE!


    def on_partition_initialize(partition_context):
        print("Partition: {} has been initialized.".format(partition_context.partition_id))

    def on_partition_close(partition_context, reason):
        print("Partition: {} has been closed, reason for closing: {}.".format(
            partition_context.partition_id,
            reason
        ))

    def on_error(partition_context, error):
        if partition_context:
            print("An exception: {} occurred during receiving from Partition: {}.".format(
                partition_context.partition_id,
                error
            ))
        else:
            print("An exception: {} occurred during the load balance process.".format(error))

    consumer_client = EventHubConsumerClient.from_connection_string(
        conn_str=self.conn_string_event_hub,
        consumer_group=self.consumer_group,
        eventhub_name=self.event_hub_name,
    )
    with consumer_client:
        consumer_client.receive(
            on_event=on_event,
            on_partition_initialize=on_partition_initialize,
            on_partition_close=on_partition_close,
            on_error=on_error,
        )
```

I know you can stop the receiver via timeout using asynco.

However, what I wanted to do is, if I receive an event with specific characteristics, I want to stop the receiver.

Either that, or stop the receiver after the first event arrives.

Is this possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can stop receiving by closing the consumer client in the `on_event` callback, as shown below.

```
    def on_event(partition_context, event):
        print("Received event from partition: {}.".format(partition_context.partition_id))
        event_json = json.loads(str(event))
        if event_json["command_status"]=="successull":
           consumer_client.close()
```